# Using Spigot to change armor attributes

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm attempting to make a spigot plugin that will turn off the knockback resistance that netherite gives you, but I'm still quite new to the plugin development scene and couldn't find anything pertaining to it in the spigot api, is there a way to go about turning off the knockback resistance or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Have you read https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/armor-attributes.366742/ ?

Answer (score 1):

At the EntityDamageByEntityEvent you could set the velocity of an player with `player.setVelocity()` to the direction the damager looks.
Prevent hitting the Player upwards too much and check if the  player is sneaking or jumping.

```
setVelocity Documentation: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/Entity.html#setVelocity(org.bukkit.util.Vector)
```

Comment: That is the correct approach to the problem. Checking that the armor is of made of netherite is to be remembered also.